# How to implement Page control in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uipagecontrol, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

I'm a beginner in iPhone programming.

I am preparing an iPhone app where I need something similar to UIPageControl. How can I implement a page control in an iPhone app?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to refer to this tutorial.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/

Here you will find how to use PageControl.

Actually it gives a whole code which you can download and test in as a sample project and then you can implement in your project as per your requirements